# Migrating data from Access to SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008, ms-access, database-migration

I have a (vb.net) program that a company uses that was running on an MS Access database. However, when some data was overwritten and lost, I decided to move it over to SQLServer.

To do this, I used a program called **Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access**, which worked great, all of the tables in the database were replicated and the records were all inserted into the SQLServer database.

However, when I run the program, I now get various errors, such as

> Key not found

or

> ODBC--connection to 'SQL Serverserver\sqlexpress' failed.

So, has anybody ever carried out this process before? If so, what is the next step to ensure that the program now accesses and manipulates the SQLServer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TToni I've read that before, I don't understand your point?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: In the future, use SQL Server's built in Import wizard, which is also available in SQL Express.

Comment: @JohnnyBones I still would have had the problem that the code needing changing though, would I not?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that you changed your method of connecting to the database in the code?

Connecting to access databases are usually done using the OleDb class. While the SQL uses another class I am not too well informed about.

It also includes a completely different data source. If you double check those parts it should be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you setup permissions/security for your new database in SQL? Does the account that your program is using have access to your SQL database? As a test, try creating an odbc connection to your database.

Comment: The server name, username, password etc are all being passed into the program through an ini connection file, which all worked